# Dividing a vector of points into two spaces

Tags: stl, cgal

I have a memory-mapped file of many millions of 3D points as a STL vector using CGAL. Given an arbitrary plane that divides the dataset into approximately equal parts, I would like to sort the dataset such that all inside points are contiguous in the vector, and likewise the outside points. This process then needs to be repeated to an arbitrary depth, creating a non axis-aligned BSP tree.

Due to the size of the dataset I would like to do this in place if possible. I have a predicate functor that I use to create a filtered_iterator, but of course that doesn't sort the points, just skips non-matching ones. So I *could* create a second vector and copy the sorted points into that, and the re-use the original vector round-robin style, but I would like to avoid that if possible, if only to keep the iterators that mark the start and end of each space.

Comment: Note that there is already a kd-tree data-structure in CGAL, it might fit your need...

Comment: True, although kd-trees use axis-aligned planes, and mine need to be arbitrarily aligned. Also (and I omitted this from my question, my bad), kd-trees store points in the leaf nodes only, and I need some points in branch nodes. But thanks for mentioning it though!

Answer (score 0):

Of course, by invoking the question gods, I received direct communication from them almost as soon as I posted!

I had simply been blind to the STL algorithm [partition](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/partition/) which does exactly what I need.